# Carry value forward in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following column

```
**CurrentStatus**
Current
NoChange
NoChange
NoChange
NoChange
Late
```

I want to mutate it so that if the value is "NoChange" it uses the prior value.

I tried:

```
myDF %>% mutate(CurrentStatus = ifelse(CurrentStatus == "NoChange", lag(CurrentStatus), CurrentStatus)
```

That doesn't seem to work -- I think it's because it does a vectorized calculation so it looks at all the lags at the same time. I need it to "roll forward". I was wondering what's the most efficient way to do this without a for loop. I specifically want to avoid a for loop as there are some grouping variables not shown that I need to be mindful of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can replace the 'NoChange' to `NA` and then use `fill`

```
library(tidyverse)
myDF %>%
    mutate(CurrentStatus = replace(CurrentStatus, CurrentStatus == "NoChange", NA)) %>%
    fill(CurrentStatus)
#  CurrentStatus
#1       Current
#2       Current
#3       Current
#4       Current
#5       Current
#6          Late
```

---

Or another option is `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
myDF$CurrentStatus <-  with(myDF, na.locf(replace(CurrentStatus, 
              CurrentStatus == "NoChange", NA)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
rfwd<-function(value,trigger)
{
  c("",value)[cummax(seq_along(value)*(trigger))+1]
}
```

and your answer would be `rfwd(CurrentStatus,CurrentStatus!="NoChange")`

```
> rfwd(LETTERS,seq_along(LETTERS)%%10==0)
 [1] ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "J" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T"
```